Loading render kernels doing every run
We have a docker container where we start blender rendering. But every time Loading render kernels takes 3 minutes from render. This only happens when running a render inside a docker container. If you run blender outside of docker, the loading is done only once. Any thoughts on what this might be related to?
It seems to me that there is no folder inside the docker container where the cache should be saved. But I can’t find where the cache is generally saved in Linux.
Blender 4.1.1
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Thank you.
Regards,
Andrii
